# Rebalancing a stock portfolio with a given amount of extra cash

Tags: linear-algebra, economics

Suppose I have an investment portfolio made up of $n$ stocks each worth $p_i$, with the count of each being $c_i$, where $i \in [1, n]$.

Let's say I've found that the optimal/target split of each asset, as a percent of my whole portfolio, is $g_i$ for each stock $i$, where the current split is $f_i$. I have recently gotten some more cash (call the amount $\Delta$) to buy stock with. Assuming that stock price has drifted somewhat, how do I determine how much more of each stock I need to buy ($\delta_i$) to realign my portfolio to the target split?

For the $n=2$ case I've determined the following but I'm wondering how this could be generalised beyond that.

$$
\begin{aligned}
V &= c_1p_1+c_2p_2 \\
V+\Delta &= (c_1+\delta_1)p_1+(c_2+\delta_2)p_2\\
\therefore \Delta &= \delta_1p_1 + \delta_2p_2 & (1) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because f_i = \frac{c_i p_i}{\sum_k c_k p_k}, g_i = \frac{(c_i+\delta_i)p_i}{\sum_k (c_k+\delta_k)p_k} \\
\frac{g_if_j}{g_jf_i} = \frac{(n_i+\delta_i)n_j}{(n_j+\delta_j)n_i} = \frac{1+\frac{\delta_i}{n_i}}{1+\frac{\delta_j}{n_j}} \\
g_i f_j \left(1 + \frac{\delta_j}{n_j}\right) = f_i g_j \left(1 + \frac{\delta_i}{n_i}\right) \\
g_if_j - f_ig_j = f_ig_jn_i^{-1}\delta_i - f_jg_in_j^{-1}\delta_j \\
g_1f_2 - f_1g_2 = f_1g_2n_1^{-1}\delta_1 - f_2g_1n_2^{-1}\delta_2 && (2) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
From (1) and (2):
$$
\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 \\\ f_1g_2n_1^{-1} & -f_2g_1n_2^{-1}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \delta_1 \\\ \delta_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Delta \\\ g_1f_2 - f_1g_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix} \delta_1 \\\ \delta_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 \\\ f_1g_2n_1^{-1} & -f_2g_1n_2^{-1}\end{bmatrix} ^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \Delta \\\ g_1f_2 - f_1g_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Does the presence of $g_1f_2 - f_1g_2$ suggest I should be looking for a matrix determinant if I want to generalise the formula e.g. $\begin{vmatrix}g_1 & f_1 \\\ g_2 & f_2 \end{vmatrix}$?

Also I realise that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703896/the-problem-of-rebalancing-an-investement-portfolio) exists but it doesn't really answer my case in the way I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are complicating things a bit.

Calculate your target allocations....

$(V+\Delta)\mathbf g$  and subtract your current allocations $V\mathbf f$

To get the values of the shares you need to purchase.

i.e.

$V\mathbf f = (c_1p_1, \cdots, c_np_n)\\
(V+\Delta)\mathbf g = (c_1p_1 + \delta_1 p_1,\cdots, c_np_n + \delta_np_n)$

$(V+\Delta)\mathbf g - V\mathbf f = (\delta_1 p_1,\cdots, \delta_n p_n)$

And the number of shares for each transaction is then $\delta_i = \frac {(V+\Delta)g_i - Vf_i}{p_i}$

Comment: Ok thanks, I can see I was definitely overcomplicating things a bit now. Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to vectorise this expression (e.g. for use in MATLAB/Octave), how would I do it? i.e. something like $\vec{\delta} = \frac{(V+\Delta)\vec{g} - V\vec{f}}{\vec{p}}$ but I get that since $\vec{p}$ is a vector it can't be directly divided like that

Comment: There is no division operation in vector algebra.  You can only divide by scalars.

Comment: I'm aware - I meant in the sense of e.g. splitting $(\delta_1 p_1, \dots, \delta_n p_n)$ into component vectors e.g. $\vec{p}^T \vec{\delta}$ and manipulating it thusly.

Comment: I have had minimal training in MATLAB but I would wager that such an operation does exist.

Comment: One more thing, how would I ensure that all $\delta_i \ge 0$? If I want to rebalance a stock portfolio from say, 60-40 to 50-50, the answer this formula gives me sometimes requires me to sell stock (when I shouldn't need to)